# Connect to MS Access remote .mdb file from php on linux

Tags: php, ms-access, odbc, jet, unixodbc

I have been digging internet for couple days, reading very old information, that leads to very old and nonexisting sites, still, I understood, what is needed to achieve my goal.

1. We have a file.mdb on server running WindowsXP, so I need to add it to ODBC data sources. I do that with simple steps, ending up with "System DSN", that allows access to that .mdb file
2. I need to install on this same server some sort of ODBC bridge, that would allow me to create remote connection to this server, making that bridge connect to servers ODBC DSN, and query out my stuff (could not find any free ODBC bridge)
3. On UNIX (FreeBSD) machine, I need to install unixODBC and php5-odbc packages, enabling connections to ODBC (already installed)
4. To connect to remote ODBC and use MS Access db driver, I need to have such a driver for unixODBC, in .so file, that is sitting inside UNIX machine (could not find any free MS Access drivers)
5. Connect to that server using PHP odbc_connect(DSN,user,password), and in DSN I need to give some connection information and driver, which I need to use (MS Access driver).

Correct me, if I'm mistaken and please give me more advice, how to achieve such a connection.

Comment: Why are you set on using a Jet/ACE data store?

Comment: There is Win software, that is generating those mdb files, very serious and OLD software, that I need to create data integration ability - use data into reports.

Comment: Maybe a software component should be created to run on Windows that converts the MDB to a more portable format, before the data ever leaves the Windows environment.

Comment: Sadly, not possible with my resources.

Comment: But that software component to run on Windows could be as simple as a VBScript that uses DAO to write data tables out to a bunch of CSV files, for instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I found solution.

1. Set up on Win server **FreeSSHd**, configure connection account and set directory to one, you need
2. Set up on unix server **sshfs**
3. Mount Win server directory with .mdb files

   sshfs {user}@:/ {unix mount point} -o workaround=rename,allow_other
4. Set up on unix server **mdbtools**

So, I used default PHP code from docs and write this PHP script:

```
$rows = $cols = array();
if (($handle = popen('/usr/bin/mdb-export {unix mount point}/{file}.mdb {table} 2>&1', 'r')) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        if ($row == 1) { for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) { $cols[] = $data[$c]; } }
        else { for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) { $rows[$row][$cols[$c]] = $data[$c]; } }
        $row++;
    }
    pclose($handle);
}
print_r($rows);
```

- Path to **/usr/bin/mdb-export** should be path to your mdb-export file (use `find / -name "mdb-export"`, if you can't find yours).
- Mount point **{unix mount point}** should be an empty file folder (I used **/usr/home/remotemdb**)
- Table **{table}** should be the table name inside mdb file. Query all possible tables inside mdb file with command `mdb-tables {unix mount point}/<file>.mdb`

There is no need for drivers, configuration or other stuff, just plain mdbtools and access to file, in this case, achieved with remote connection through ssh. In you want, you can install fuse package, to autmatically mount remote directory, but that is another question.

Hope someone this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You don't connect to a "server dsn". DSN's are a local thing only. They're not exposed for remote connections at all. If you want a machine to connect to a database, you need to have a DSN configured on that machine - you won't be able to use a DSN specified elsewhere.

For PHP ODBC, that'd be

```
$connection = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=/network/path/to/your/access/database.mdb", $user, $password);
```

Comment: The question was, what software (prefered freeware) exacty do I need, to enable connections to those local DSN's?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct insomuch that you require an ODBC to ODBC Bridge.

At [OpenLInk](http://www.openlinksw.com) we refer to a [Multi-tier ODBC to ODBC Bridge](http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-odbc-mt/)...

This is Multi-tier in the sense that it has a client/server architecture as follows --

Linux Client --
  ODBC Application
  OpenLink Generic ODBC Driver

Windows Server --
  32bit OpenLink request Broker
  32bit OpenLink ODBC Agent
  32bit Microsoft Access ODBC Driver (with pre configured DSN)
  Microsoft Access Database file.

Comment: Thats commercial too. I would like some freeware bridge, as I'm not dealing with commercial stuff. And BTW, that software is outdated! Theres only old FreeBSD 5.4 avilable, currently using 8th version. Cmon, and you want me to pay for outdated product? :( But still, thanks for info...

Answer (score 0):

Its commercial, so possibly not of interest, but Easysoft have an ODBC driver for Access that's available on Most *nix's. No bridge required. There isn't a build on FreeBSD at the moment, but I could get one built for you on Monday if it's of any interest.

There is the open source MDB tools that may have enough for what you want, but it is lacking in quite a lot of functionality.

[Easysoft Access ODBC Driver](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-access-driver/index.html)

[MDB tools](http://mdbtools.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: That is quite the same, as I mentioned in my answer above... But thanks for offer!

Answer (score 0):

Use PDO with MDBTools:

install:

apt-get install libodbc1

apt-get install libmdbodbc1

apt-get install php5-odbc

(restart apache)

Sample:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM Table';
$mdb_file = 'file.mdb';
$driver = 'MDBTools';
$dataSourceName = "odbc:Driver=$driver;DBQ=$mdb_file;Uid=user;Pwd=pass;";
$connection = new \PDO($dataSourceName);
$result = $connection->query($query)->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($result);
```